# Why doesn't Chrome wrap a centered column to the next line in bootstrap 4 beta?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

I use bootstrap 4 beta. What I would like to do is center a line of text inside a column, and if the text exceeds the line width, it should wrap to next line.

I use justify-content-center on the row, in combination with col-auto on the col to horizontally center. The centering works, but the wrap to next line doesn't.

Here's what it looks like:

Nicely centers if there is just a short text:
[image]

Doesn't wrap to next line if it's a long text in Chrome:
[image]

Here is my code:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.0.0-beta/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
   <div class="row justify-content-xl-center justify-content-lg-center justify-content-md-center justify-content-sm-center justify-content-center" style="background:red">
     <div class="col col-xl-auto col-lg-auto col-md-auto col-sm-auto col-auto">
        A very long title is printed here in this example. I wonder why it doesn't wrap to the next line?
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o9b17p2d/6/).

Comment: No repro for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: A Chrome browser.

Comment: Good to know; it works properly in Firefox. I've updated the question to mention this is Chrome-specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.0.0-beta/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="background:red; text-align:center;">
    <div class="col col-xl-auto col-lg-auto col-md-auto col-sm-auto col-auto" style="width:100%;">
      A very long title is printed here in this example. I wonder why it doesn't wrap to the next line?
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution wraps long text to next line as required, but if the text is short it no longer centers it. So your solution won't work.

Comment: updated the answer, try this. it's alright in jsfiddle

Comment: @brinch max-width : 100% works fine too ;) (FF has no issue by the way) else reset the flex value to 1 to avoid dealing with static width : https://jsfiddle.net/o9b17p2d/7/

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.0.0-beta/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 text-center">
    A very long title is printed here in this example. I wonder why it doesn't wrap to the next line?
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thx Rory O'Kane